# Global Hooks not working in Visual C++

Tags: c++, qt, setwindowshookex

I've written this basic C++ app for understanding the Windows Global Hooks since I'm new to it. Unfortunately, this works perfect on the Qt Creator but not that well in the Visual Studio. In fact, it does nothing in the VS2013. Anyone who could elaborate why? It'd be really helpful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HHOOK hHook{ NULL };

LRESULT CALLBACK MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc(const int nCode, const WPARAM wParam, const LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Key Pressed!";
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (hHook == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Hook failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've followed the tutorial [given here](https://www.youtube.com/embed/O0C4V6JmlNw). I've also tried consulting many online documentations but i couldn't fix it maybe because I usually work in C# and not C++.

**UPDATE**: Here's how the Qt application looks like. Its almost the same, just the main function is a bit different and std::cout is replaced with QDebug(). Also there are some additional #include.

```
#include<QtCore/QCoreApplicaton>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QTime>
#include<QChar>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (hHook == NULL) {
        QDebug() << "Hook failed!";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The current program will set the hook and terminate immediately. How does your Qt program look like?

Comment: @trenki exactly! That's the problem. Qt program looks kind of similar, i've updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first application will set the hook but then terminate the program immediately.

The Qt Application with the `return a.exec()` runs a message loop that will only terminate when you close the program. That is why it stays open.

**EDIT:**

You have to "pump the windows message loop", try the following code ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows))

```
MSG msg;
BOOL bRet;

while((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
{
    if(bRet == -1)
    {
        // Handle Error
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

In the case you receive a `WM_QUIT` message you can terminate the program.

Comment: that doesn't work. But i guess i found a solution online. Let me post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler and easier way would be to put the following line of code just before the return statement.

```
while (GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0));
```

Comment: @trenki check this out.